# Generate original File from text

Tags: php

The thing i have is a backup data from a DB. that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `accFiles` (
  `accfile_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `accfile_accountId` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `accfile_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `accfile_type` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `accfile_size` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `accfile_content` mediumblob NOT NULL,
  `accfile_extension` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`accfile_id`),
  KEY `IDX_accountId` (`accfile_accountId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `accFiles` VALUES(1,6,"test.txt","text/plain",27,"test\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntsert","TXT");
INSERT INTO `accFiles` VALUES(2,6,"test.txt","text/plain",27,"test\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntsert","TXT");


CREATE TABLE.....
```

Now i have written a php script that gets the content part and writes it in a file with the same name as provided by the 3 value. The php is written to get the first Line get the Name and Content and creates a File with that name and writes the content in it.

```
<?php
//error_reporting(0);
$file = $argv[1];         //read console parameter
$filep = file_get_contents($file);//get content
$s1="INSERT INTO `accFiles`";     //Search the accfile part
$pos=strpos($filep,$s1);    //first File
$end=strrpos($filep,$s1);   //last file
$ind=0;

do{ // walk through file by file
    $pos2=strpos($filep,$s1,$pos + 5);
    $whant[$ind]=substr($filep,$pos+29,$pos2-$pos-30);
    $ind++;
    $pos=$pos2;
}while(is_numeric($pos2) && $end>=$pos2);


$whant[$ind-1]=substr($filep,$end+29,strpos($filep,"CREATE TABLE",$end)-$end-32); // last file

//echo $whant[0]."\n";
//echo $whant[1]."\n";
$theidd = explode(",",$whant[0]);
$filename = trim($theidd[2],"\"");


$input = substr($whant[0],strpos($whant[0],$theidd[5])+1,strrpos($whant[0],",")-strpos($whant[0],$theidd[5])-2); //get content of file 1

$myfile = fopen(dirname(__FILE__)."/".$filename, "w",1);
fwrite($myfile, $input);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

So i think the problem is that he writes the data exactly like it is in the new txt file so the content is test\ntest\n insted of real new lines.
Funny part is when i have .jpg files or .gif they are stored exactly the same way the content was to long i would have posted it in here.
But i whant to be able to get the original picture or what ever file it is back.

Answer (score 0):

A more portable option would be to install MySQL and import the backup of your database. Then you can easily do the following:

```
select accfile_name, accfile_content from accFiles
```

Iterate over the returned result and write each file to disk, as in the following code snippet:

```
$outputdir = "/home/matthias/output/";
$sql = "select accfile_name, accfile_content from accFiles";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $db_con);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  $filename = $row['accfile_name'];
  $content = $row['accfile_content'];
  $path = $outputdir . $filename;
  $file = fopen($path, $content);
  $fclose($file);
}
```

Comment: sorry but i can only work with the php file and the backupFile i have of the database.